# Use regular expression to find character sequences

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex expression that detects wheather any character sequence exceeds a specified threshold in a string

for example:

the string "aaaxyzbbbb" is valid if threshold = 4;

```
ValidateString(input strToValidate, int threshold)
{

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask. What threshold are you talking about, exactly?

Comment: can u be more detailed ?

Comment: Threshold equals the number of times a character repeats. From the example `aaaxyzbbbb` is valid because `bbbb` meets a threshold of 4.

Comment: Are you expecting us to just write the code for you?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary - How do you know that that's what the OP means by "threshold"? OP's wording was entirely unclear.

Comment: Years of SO experience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pattern that looks something like `(.)\1{N}` where `N` represents some number which should be your threshold minus one.

The pattern means:

- `(.)` - any character, capturing it in a group
- `\1`  - followed by whatever was matched in the first group
- `{N}` - match the previous thing N times

So, for example, `(.)\1{3}` means any character followed by three more of the same character.